# VLOOKUP return based on partial Match |Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets. Sheet 2 contains keywords and its corresponding value. Sheet 1 contains some URL. If the url has the keyword from sheet2 A1 then it has to print its corresponding value. I tried wild card but NULL zero. please help I'm new to excel formulas.

Sheet 1
[Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr6ZE.png)

Sheet 2
[Sheet 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8gKT.png)

Output
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67V1Q.png)

I tried wild card but returns zero.

`=VLOOKUP("*"&A2&"*",Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use:
`=FILTER(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$1,$A1)),"")`

And if you want to expand the list of lookup and return values, expand the row numbers for the ranges of Sheet2:
`=FILTER(Sheet2!$B$1:$B$2,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$2,$A1)),"")`

`SEARCH` looks up the values in column A of Sheet2 to be present in the cell of Sheet1 and returns an array of the position of each search value found within the text, or an error value if not found. The `ISNUMBER` converts this to TRUE for numbers, or FALSE for error values.
This is used to filter column B of Sheet2.

*If multiple returns are possible, wrap it in `TRANSPOSE()` so it spills the results to the right instead of down over the next formula, causing a spill error*

Comment: Hi @p.b i dont have filter version in my excel could you please give any alternative

Comment: i have used this formula it giving the results
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,1/ISNUMBER(FIND(Sheet2!A:A,A2))*ROW(Sheet2!A:A),1)),"")

I have 1M data which takes more time to process 8threads  is there any way to optimize it

Comment: Yes, updating to Microsoft 365 and using FILTER, lol. But instead of using whole column references you may use ranges large enough to cover the data, but small enough to not slow things down too much.  But overall in older Excel you need to accept the calculation time or find solution in VBA.